# UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: when building android project

Tags: android

After adding the SherlockAction Bar as a module to my IntelliJ project. I get the following stackTrace. If you need more information about my project, please tell me

```
Error:[AndroidApp] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
Error:[AndroidApp] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/codehaus/classworlds/uberjar/boot/Bootstrapper;
Error:[AndroidApp] at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:123)
Error:[AndroidApp] at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:163)
Error:[AndroidApp] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:490)
Error:[AndroidApp] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:459)
Error:[AndroidApp] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$400(Main.java:67)
Error:[AndroidApp] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:398)
Error:[AndroidApp] at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:245)
Error:[AndroidApp] at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:131)
Error:[AndroidApp] at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:109)
Error:[AndroidApp] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:422)
Error:[AndroidApp] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:333)
Error:[AndroidApp] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:209)
Error:[AndroidApp] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error:[AndroidApp] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
Error:[AndroidApp] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
Error:[AndroidApp] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
Error:[AndroidApp] at org.jetbrains.android.compiler.tools.AndroidDxRunner.runDex(AndroidDxRunner.java:139)
Error:[AndroidApp] at org.jetbrains.android.compiler.tools.AndroidDxRunner.main(AndroidDxRunner.java:261)
Error:[AndroidApp] at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:121)
Error:[AndroidApp] 1 error; aborting
```

Comment: so what's on line 121 at CommandLineWrapper.java?

Comment: Thanks but I don't see any duplicate dependency. I use IntelliJ without the classpath file

Answer (score 1):

From the following error message:

```
Error:[AndroidApp] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/codehaus/classworlds/uberjar/boot/Bootstrapper;
```

We know IntelliJ IDEA attempted to add `Bootstrapper` class more than once at compile time. In other words, IntelliJ IDEA attempted to load two or more identical libraries and/or `jar`s containing `Bootstrapper` class at compile time.

### Suggested Solution:

Make sure to avoid duplicate libraries in your Project.

**Step 1:**

Go to `File -> Project Structure`, then check the following places with a particular attention:

1. Platform Settings -> Global Libraries
2. Project Settings -> Libraries

**Step #2:**

Check Module-specific library folder (i.e. `ROOT_OF_THE_PROJECT/libs/*`).

**Step #3:**

Make sure not to include `.jar` file(s) *again* manually. For example, you may have accidentally added the following:

1. a library folder (including `/`, `src/`, `res/`, etc.)
2. `.jar` from `/libs/SOME-PROBLEMATIC-JAR-FILE.jar`

This case, you can simply exclude (or delete) `/libs/SOME-PROBLEMATIC-JAR-FILE.jar` from the Project.

Comment: After fixing the problem a "mvn clean" might be necessary!